# Are void methods at their most basic faster/less of an overhead than methods that return a value?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, il

I cannot find a similar question/answer either here on SO or on the internet, and as useless as this question maybe it is a question that came to my mind whilst doing some reading on MSIL. I am very curious to understand how IL operation execution works in my scenario, even if this is not a practical question I have no one else to ask.

**Premise:**

Bearing in mind that the execution of both MSIL commands and functions is done in three steps:

1. Push command operands or function parameters onto the stack.
2. Execute the MSIL command or call function. The command or function pops their operands (parameters) from the stack and pushes onto the stack result (return value).
3. Read result from the stack.

Steps 1 and 3 are optional. For example, the void function doesn't push a return value to the stack.

I understand that it is what a method does that determines how much 'processing-power' is required, but for the sake of my curiosity lets consider these two very basic methods:

First method:

```
void Method1()
{
  var result = 1+1;
}
```

Second method:

```
int Method2()
{
  var result = 1+1;
  return result;
}
```

**Question:**

Because the void method doesn't push a return value (or is there an implicit return) does this mean that it requires less overhead when executing  as opposed to the second method?

Comment: Let's assume, that `void` methods are faster, than returning value methods. Will you stop to write the code, containing non-void methods?

Comment: A clever compiler wouldn't even bother to ever use Method1, since it can never have any effect on the program.

Comment: Perhaps a more useful question would be to ask if a `ref` parameter is slower than a method with a return value. For your example you would need a "global" variable of some sort to achieve the same thing. (ie get the result of 1+1 so you can do something with it as currently it is simply discarded in the `void`)

That aside, I have no clue :) But does it matter? Having all your code inline is definitely going to be faster than calling methods. But I don't think that would be a good argument for putting all your code in some monster method.

Comment: Keep in mind that returning a value is just storing the value in a register. Most likely whatever calculation the method is doing will place the value in the needed register.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember, though, that MSIL is not executed or even interpreted. MSIL is an expression of the compiled code as it would be executed on the virtual machine. But the JIT compiler converts MSIL to machine code (x86, etc.). The x86 is fundamentally different from the stack-based virtual machine.

At the most basic level, functions return values in registers. Assuming that the registers are large enough. Let's stick with 64-bit values (references, long integers, doubles, and smaller value types). Those can be returned in the RAX register. In your trivial example, there would be no difference in the generated machine code for the two functions. That is, `Method1` would be:

```
mov rax, 1
inc rax
ret
```

(And, yes, I know that a smart compiler would collapse `1+1` to `2`. Let's assume that there was a memory access there, okay?)

`Method2` would be identical because the value to be returned is already in the RAX register.

So when you're working with 64 bit or smaller quantities, the difference between a method that returns a value and a method that doesn't return a value will most often differ, if at all, only in whatever instruction it takes to load the return value into the proper register. This is typically a single `mov` instruction. It's going to depend on the order in which things are done, and also on how well the compiler and JITer optimize things.

Comment: So it really just boils down to the mov instruction?

Comment: In my example I used an int, but if I were to use a different type much larger than an int, wouldn't that have a larger impact?

Comment: @Monkieboy: if you're returning a value type that's smaller than 64 bits (I'm assuming a program running in 64 bit mode here), or if you're returning a reference (i.e. an object), then the value can be returned in a register. How larger value types are returned is an implementation detail that I don't know. They could be returned in multiple registers, or they could be allocated in the heap and a reference returned in a register, or they could be returned on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain to me Jim, my examples were not that great but I do understand a bit more thanks to both answers. I will give you the tick because you provided an answer that revealed how they can differ in IL.

Answer (score 3):

All things being even, doing something is going to be slower than not doing something.

Note though, that the implementation of the first method is going to be turned into:

```
void Method1()
{
}
```

After inlining, it isn't even called (it's just about possible that the call gets replaced by a read of a field, if this is an instance method on another object, since the optimisation can't stop the `NullReferenceException()` it should throw if called on null. If it's static, called from the same object, or the compiler determines the object can't be null, then not even that. Zero code.

Meanwhile, the second method will be turned into:

```
int Method2()
{
  return 2;
}
```

After inlining, a call that uses the value would be turned from e.g:

```
x = Method2();
```

To:

```
x = 2;
```

If the value isn't used, then not even that; it'll be exactly the same as the first.

This sort of thing going on means that even in cases where calls aren't inlined, such tiny differences as whether or not something is returned will mostly be lost as not even noise against the bigger factors, and also can happen counter-intuitively (by affecting whether or not some optimisation path is taken in some obscure way). Example: Value is produced, it's "returned" by putting it in a register, but maybe it was there anyway upon calculation, maybe it's next use works on it directly there; hence zero cost to "return" it.

Comment: Excellent explanation that pretty much says what Jim has said just without the IL breakdown, thanks for taking the time to help.